# Order of process.stdout.on( 'data', ... ) and process.stderr.on( 'data', ... )

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm writing an electron app and this app deals with terminal commands executed from within electron.

I've got troubles with the execution of the `npm ls` command. When running it from the cli the dependency tree is printed to stdout and right at the end some warning might appear coming from stderr.

See screenshot below.

[correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D0Nq.png)

I digged `npm` source code a bit and it logs out the results first and afterwards it prints errors. So it's exactly like I see it in my terminal.

However when I do the same with `child_process` `spawn` ( or `exec` it doesn't matter ), the order is different.

[puzzled output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwJJd.png)

It looks like because of the big chunks of `stdout` data the `stderr` is printed right in the middle of all the `stdout`.

The code I wrote below:

```
// this is mapped to require( 'child_process' ).spawn
this.$set( 'process', this.spawn(
  'npm',
  [ 'ls' ],
  {
    cwd   : options.cwd,

    // following are only my tryouts - nothing helped :(

    // some npm ls command destroy kill the scripts
    // with too big buffers in stdout
    // maxBuffer : 1024 * 5000
    // shell : true
  }
) );

// this.handleData is only printing out for nwo
this.process.stdout.on( 'data', this.handleData );
this.process.stderr.on( 'data', this.handleData );
```

It seams when large data comes from `stdout` and tiny data coming from `stderr` that `stderr` somehow gets called in the middle.

Is this expected behavior? Can I work around this somehow to retrieve the same behavior as in my terminal?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

`process.stdout` and `process.stderr` are not guaranteed to emit data in any particular order relative to each other, so as you've noticed, your callback may be called whenever there's any amount of data in either pipe.

If you want to make sure that the `stderr` is handled only once all of `stdout` is finished, you might want to listen to `stdout.on('end', cb)` and only call `stderr.on('data', this.handleData)` in that callback `cb`.

---

That said, if you just want the results of `npm ls`, perhaps you might consider trying to [use the `npm` module programmatically](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm#using-npm-programmatically)?  The documentation isn't amazing, but it's a higher-level API.

Comment: I thought about that, too. Use case is to update on any `stdout` or `stderr`. When I wait for all `stdout` to be done until I catch the `stderr` this might lead to different problems with other commands, that need an `stderr` in the middle. :(

The npm command is only the case where I discovered it. There could be completely different commands.