# Please see my problem, believe me it is easy to solve

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x, python-2.7

i tried to implement async and await inside spawn child process. But it didn't worked. Please see this

Expected output

```
 *************
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/
 *************
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/personal-injury.html
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/personal-injury.html
 *************
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/#
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/#
 *************
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/home.html
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/home.html
 *************
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/about-us.html
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/about-us.html
 *************
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/

 *************
```

Becoz each time spawn child found `await` it will go back to python script and print  `*************` it and then print URL. Ignore 2 times printing of same url here.

Output which i m getting

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\searchermc>node app.js
server running on port 3000

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52966/devtools/browser/933c20c7-e295-4d84-a4b8-eeb5888ecbbf
[3020:120:0402/105304.190:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [10:53:04.188] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1056 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[3020:120:0402/105304.190:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [10:53:04.189] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1056 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)

 *************
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/personal-injury.html
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/personal-injury.html
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/#
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/#
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/home.html
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/home.html
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/about-us.html
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/about-us.html
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/
http://www.stevecostellolaw.com/

 *************
```

Please see the `app.js` code below

```
// form submit request
app.post('/formsubmit', function(req, res){

    csvData = req.files.csvfile.data.toString('utf8');
    filteredArray = cleanArray(csvData.split(/\r?\n/))
    csvData = get_array_string(filteredArray)
    csvData = csvData.trim()
    
    var keywords = req.body.keywords
    keywords = keywords.trim()

    // Send request to python script
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var process = spawn('python', ["./webextraction.py", csvData, keywords, req.body.full_search])

    var outarr = []

    // process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    //   console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    // });

    process.stdout.on('data', async function(data){

      console.log("\n ************* ")
      console.log(data.toString().trim())
      await outarr.push(data.toString().trim())
      console.log("\n ************* ")

    });

});
```

Python function which is sending in the URLs when the if condition matched

```
# Function for searching keyword start
def search_keyword(href, search_key):
    extension_list = ['mp3', 'jpg', 'exe', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf', 'vcf']
    if(href.split('.')[-1] not in extension_list):
        try:    
            content = selenium_calling(href)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')
            search_string = re.sub("\s+"," ", soup.body.text)
            search_string = search_string.lower()
            res = [ele for ele in search_key if(ele.lower() in search_string)]
            outstr = getstring(res)
            outstr = outstr.lstrip(", ")
            if(len(res) > 0):
                print(href)
                found_results.append(href)
                href_key_dict[href] = outstr
                return 1
            else:
                notfound_results.append(href)
        except Exception as err:
            pass
```

I want to do all this because of the python script which takes more time to execute and thus give timeout error each time, so i am thinking to get intermediate ouput of the python script in my nodejs script. you can see the error i m getting in below image.

[image]

Comment: `await outarr.push(data.toString().trim())` doesn't make sense; `Array.push()` doesn't return a Promise.

Comment: 5 minutes.  You waited 5 minutes before complaining that no one had yet volunteered free consulting advice on a problem crossing two different languages???

Comment: @ChrisG i want all returned URLs in separate index of array, please can you see this i m struggling for more than week becoz of lack of concept

Comment: @TimRoberts u can check my profile i have rephrased same question many times but no reply i received

Comment: @TimRoberts you can see  questions `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66903762/how-to-return-intermediate-output-of-python-and-save-it-in-array-inside-spawn-pr` `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66704265/please-see-this-nodejs-application-on-heroku-crashing-after-30-sec-http-request` `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66650556/how-to-use-async-await-in-python-child-process`

Comment: You should understand first `spawn`  doesn't return the promises instead a stream, so you can't use async/await for it. check [here](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-execfile-spawn-exec-and-fork-in-node) to understand the working and its return signature.

Comment: hi can u suggest any otherway to achieve this

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara can you see it and suggest me any other way.

Comment: Why do you want to do other way, it seems efficient as it uses stream to do the work even if you have a big file it will more efficient instead of waiting on each group URLs. Spawn is great when you have long running process.

Comment: @Nickjones you aren't ever ending the request in your endpoint. Node/express (which I assume you're using here) won't end a request until you tell it to, regardless of if your script is finished. If you don't want to wait for the process to finish, remove the await on outarr.push and add return res.send(outarr). However, keep in mind that your data handler will be called every time new data comes from the script, so unless you wait for it to finish you won't be able to capture the full output, obviously.

Comment: @Nickjones I think the trouble you're getting with no one answering these questions is that the concept of what you're trying to do doesn't really seem to make sense. If you want to capture all of the output from a script, the script needs to finish running. If you don't want to capture the output (or if you want to end the request while the script finishes), you need to end the request manually with res.end or res.send, if you have any data to send back. But again, you won't have any guaranteed data unless you let the script you're running finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to do, but I'll give it a shot since you seem to have asked this question many times already (which usually isn't a good idea). I believe that there's a lack of clarity in your question - it would help a lot if you could clarify what your end goal is (i.e. how do you want this to behave?)

I think you mentioned two separate problems here. The first is that you expect a new line of '******' to be placed before each separate piece of data returned from your script. This is something that can't be relied on - check out the answer to this question for more detail: [Order of process.stdout.on( 'data', ... ) and process.stderr.on( 'data', ... )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38643264/order-of-process-stdout-on-data-and-process-stderr-on-data). The data will be passed to your stdout handler in chunks, not line-by-line, and any amount of data can be provided at a time depending how much is currently in the pipe.

The part I'm most confused about is your phrasing of "to get intermediate ouput of the python script in my nodejs script". There's not necessarily any "immediate" data - you can't rely on data coming in at any particular time with your process's stdout handler, its going to hand you data at a pace determined by the Python script itself and the process its running in. With that said, it sounds like your main problem here is the timeout happening on your POST. You aren't ever ending your request - that's why you're getting a timeout. I'm going to assume that you want to wait for the first chunk of data - regardless of how many lines it contains - before sending a response back. In that case, you'll need to add res.send, like this:

```
    // form submit request
app.post('/formsubmit', function(req, res){

    csvData = req.files.csvfile.data.toString('utf8');
    filteredArray = cleanArray(csvData.split(/\r?\n/))
    csvData = get_array_string(filteredArray)
    csvData = csvData.trim()
    
    var keywords = req.body.keywords
    keywords = keywords.trim()

    // Send request to python script
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var process = spawn('python', ["./webextraction.py", csvData, keywords, req.body.full_search])

    var outarr = []

    // process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    //   console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    // });
    
    // Keep track of whether we've already ended the request
    let responseSent = false;

    process.stdout.on('data', async function(data){

        console.log("\n ************* ")
        console.log(data.toString().trim())
        outarr.push(data.toString().trim())
        console.log("\n ************* ")
        
        // If the request hasn't already been ended, send back the current output from the script
        // and end the request
        if (!responseSent) {
            responseSent = true;
            res.send(outarr);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: here is my complete code https://github.com/rinku16/keysearch

Comment: @Nickjones I don't need to see all your code, I was asking you to explain the intended outcome of your code. You make some conflicting statements about async code, when you want your request to return, and what data you want to use. Did you have any questions about my answer, or did it answer your question?

Comment: i appreciate your effort let me check this

Comment: I tried to solve the issue of timeout by receiving output of python as `if` condition matched in my python script, so earlier i was storing all crawled data in dataframe and then retuning the dataframe to nodejs script but i think this is making issue of timeout, so i started thinking of to get the url as it matched from the python script to nodejs script and then save it in array declared in the ndoejs script

Comment: No matter what, you current code will time out. The timeout is happening because you aren't ending the request. Check out the third paragraph of my answer - you HAVE to end the request at some point. If you don't end the request with res.send or res.end, the request will stay open and it WILL time out. The reason its timing out has nothing to do with your script, at least not in your current code. You MUST add in res.send() or res.end() at some point before the 30 second timeout happens, otherwise it will time out on every request.

Comment: sorry but when you see in my `app.js` code file, go to line number `81-87` and `113-117` you will see that i m returning csv file. please visit my github link above

Comment: My answer was written off of the code that you posted in your question. If the code in your GitHub is different, it likely has a completely different problem. I'm not willing to investigate a whole new set of code and write a new answer for it. I'd highly recommend editing your question to post the correct code, and in the future don't post disconnected code that you're not using. Good luck!

Comment: can we use spawn child process inside for loop

Comment: thank god you got me right, i pray GOD for adding 1000*1000 years to your life

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! I'm definitely a bit confused as to which code is the one you're using, but as long as things are working, that's the important part. It might also help to do some more reading up on Express for Node, as it is very important to understand when working on APIs like these. Good luck!

Comment: No things are not working but i will accept this answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230666/discussion-between-nick-jones-and-joseph).